# Computing number of filled columns in SQL table

Tags: sql

I have a SQL table with 6 columns. 1 ID int column and 5 Datetime columns Round1, Round2, ..., Round5

The data looks something like this. Either there is a date or the cell is empty.

[image]

I would like the query to show the number of filled datetime columns. That is

[image]

Can you please give some hint on how to build this query? Would this involve aggregate function?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `CASE` expressions to return 1 when a value is not `NULL` or 0 otherwise. Then just add all that.

```
SELECT id,
       CASE
         WHEN round1 IS NOT NULL THEN
           1
         ELSE
           0
       END
       +
       ...
       CASE
         WHEN round5 IS NOT NULL THEN
           1
         ELSE
           0
       END total
       FROM elbat;
```

And next time do not post images of tables. Post their `CREATE` statements with sample data as `INSERT` statements. And tag the specific DBMS you're using.

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
SELECT ID, IIf(Round1 Is Null, 0, 1) + IIf(Round2 Is Null, 0, 1) + 
IIf(Round 3 Is Null, 0, 1) + IIf(Round4 Is Null, 0, 1) + IIf(Round5 Is Null, 0, 1) AS Cnt
FROM Table;
```

Aggregate function is not helpful unless you first normalize the data with UNION query.

```
SELECT ID, Round1 AS Dte, "R1" AS Src FROM table
UNION SELECT ID, Round2, "R2" FROM table
UNION SELECT ID, Round3, "R3" FROM table
UNION SELECT ID, Round4, "R4" FROM table
UNION SELECT ID, Round5, "R5" FROM table;
```

Then use that query in aggregate SQL.

```
SELECT ID, Count(Dte) AS CntD FROM Q1 GROUP BY ID;
```